# How to implement a file download in MeanJS application

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, multer

Im a mobile app developer and new to web apps. Im trying to implement upload and download a file in the web app using MeanJS stack. I have used multer plugin to upload file to server. After a lot of googling I have successfully used Multer which uploads and saves the files to uploads directory. 
Now Im trying to implement download the same, and I don't have an idea to do this. I have followed two methods:

1. `<a target="_self" href="/uploads/{{eachDocument.modifiedFileName}}" download="{{eachDocument.fileName}}">{{eachDocument.fileName}}</a>`
2. Have used a route in the express server controller, as given in http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download

Using the method #1 application never downloads the file with an error "Not a file", because uploads is not the public directory.

Using method #2, I'm able to get the raw file content, but not sure how to save the file.

Can anyone please tell me how to implement the file download that are saved in uploads directory that were uploaded using multer.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code used in method#2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sridhar Chidurala, please find my code for the server and view controller:

I'm using the following code for server controller :

```
var file = __dirname + "/../../" + results.filePath;
 res.download(file, results.filename, function (err) {
     if (err) {
     } else {
     }
  });
```

On the view controller, Im posting some data and based on the data I get the file data to the view.:

```
$http.post(requestString, reqObject).
  success(function (response) {
    // **I get the file data here**
    console.log("success response : " + JSON.stringify(response));
   }).error(function (response) {
     console.log("error response : " + JSON.stringify(response));
   });
```